# Number of planar bipartite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, bipartite-graphs, planar-graphs

How many planar bipartite graphs are there with $m$ vertices of one color and $n$ vertices of the other color?

How many non-isomorphic classes exist?